# How to design Database for an e-commerce site

Tags: sql

I want to design a Db for an e-commerce site. The web application will provide facility to users to register as a business owner and then they will be able to perform CURD operation on their items. While the buyers or clients, will able to search for a particular product or business name, based on the search criteria results will be shown to clients. when the buyers will click a product from filtered results the buyer will be taken to that business page.
Based on the description I designed a DB but I'm not sure will it work or not?
Kindly go through and suggest changes as well as relations
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICJUZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

First of all we cannot see all the data items there because we cannot actually scroll in the image. The Design looks okay to me and is normalized to some extent, I cannot be sure unless I see the whole thing though.

Database Designs these days aren't simple like it used to be and with new technologies out in the market it is getting complicated day by day. I know people who don't go for normalization and okay with repeating the data in different collections or tables so that the actual machine operation is reduced. With nosql databases it has becomes easier to have big chunks of data with very good turnaround time.

Why do you think it wont work BTW?

Comment: Suppose two columns, A and B have many to many relationship but the primary keys of both columns are of different type. Now, In junction Table will it work  to have foreign keys of table A and B of different type?

Comment: I'd like to have a look at the ERD for what you just said